# Qt MouseTracking in QTableWidget

Tags: qt, qt4

I want to enable mouseTracking in a QTableWidget using Qt4.7. Usually this should be straight forward with setMouseTracking(true). This worked on other widgets, but QTableWidget resists it. Is there anything special I have to deal with in order to activate mouseTracking?

Although i'm actually doing more complex stuff i could gain confidence that its not enabled by printing out QMouseEvent.x() in mouseMoveEvent. 
thanks so far :)

Here is what I tried:

```
    QGridLayout * layout = new QGridLayout(this);
    SCTableWidget * aTable = new SCTableWidget(tableRows, tableCols, this);

    QTableWidgetItem * newItem;
    for(int i = 0; i<(3); i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j<(17); j++) {
            newItem = new QTableWidgetItem(QString::number(tableData[i][j]));
            aTable->setItem(i,j, newItem);
        }
    }

// First try
    aTable->setMouseTracking(true);

//Second try. Main Window further down.
    MainWindow::instance->enableMouseTracking(aTable->children());
    MainWindow::instance->enableMouseTracking(aTable->viewport()->children());


// Third try
    aTable->viewport()->setMouseTracking(true);

    layout->addWidget(aTable, 0, 0, 1, 2);
```

The second try contains a method that is implemented in MainWindow which looks like this:

```
void
MainWindow::enableMouseTracking(const QObjectList & pChildren)
{
  foreach(QObject * obj, pChildren)
  {
    QWidget * w = qobject_cast<QWidget *>(obj);

    if(w)
    {
      w->setMouseTracking(true);
      enableMouseTracking(w->children());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 for well-document efforts to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

switching on mouse tracking for QTableWidget->viewport() usually works. Are you also catching mouse events for the QTableWidget->viewport() widget? Pls check if an example below would work fine for you:

test.h:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

    bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event);

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QTableWidget *table;
};
```

test.cpp:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    table = new QTableWidget(5, 10, this);
    table->setGeometry(10, 20, 300, 200);

    for (int row=0; row<5; ++row)
        for (int column=0; column<10; ++column)
            table->setItem(row, column, new QTableWidgetItem(tr("%1").arg((row+1)*(column+1))));

    table->setMouseTracking(true);
    table->viewport()->setMouseTracking(true);
    table->installEventFilter(this);
    table->viewport()->installEventFilter(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
    if (obj == table)
    {
        if (event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress)
            qDebug() << "table mouse press event";
        else if (event->type() == QEvent::MouseMove)
            qDebug() << "table mouse moveevent";
    }
    else if (obj == table->viewport())
    {
        if (event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress)
            qDebug() << "table->viewport mouse press event";
        else if (event->type() == QEvent::MouseMove)
            qDebug() << "table->viewport mouse moveevent";
    }
    return QMainWindow::eventFilter(obj, event);
}
```

hope this helps, regards

Comment: thanks! I haven't thought that its possible to connect the event filter to the viewport as well. I am doing some eventHandling in the Event Filter now. Is this fine or considered bad style?

Comment: from my understanding event filters are perfectly fine: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/eventsandfilters.html

Answer (score 2):

By default, the mouse events are disabled because `QAbstractItemView` implements the `mousePressEvent`, `mouseReleaseEvent`, etc functions, and `QTableWidget` doesn't implement them at all, this means the mouse messages are blocked by the functions in `QAbstractItemView`.

So one very easy way to resolve this issue is to subclass the `QTableWidget` class, and provide the mouse signals by yourself, it should be very easy, just try it!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
    aTable->setMouseTracking(true);
    aTable->viewport()->setMouseTracking(true);
```